# Is it possible to download into page html?

Tags: php, jquery, html, download, progress-bar

Is it possible to download file inside page HTML and not in browser using jQuery or pPHP ?

By the way, Have a progress bar to show us the percent.

I know Facebook uses this system for upload (albums photos).

Thanks.

Something like this :

[image]

Not in browser like this :

http://f.cl.ly/items/0D3I13472m103j2x2J1N/Capture%20d%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran%202013-01-16%20%C3%A0%2021.05.17.png

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Where would it be downloaded to?

Comment: no. it's not possible. by definition the html is inside a browser already.

Comment: Mention what file? Text file? What will be the size?

Comment: Can you check my edit please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible, nor should it be. Users don't want you to manage their downloads in your buggy page-specific JavaScript app. Users want their downloads managed in a single place, on their browser's downloads screen, where there are already progress bars. Making your page deviate from the accepted way that *every other page* works is generally a very bad idea unless you have an exceptional reason for doing so.

In the case of uploads, the addition of page-specific uploaders with progress bars is beneficial to user experience. In the case of downloads, absolutely *nobody* wants specific websites to give you specific download UIs.

Comment: You seem to know quite a lot about absolutely everybody.

Comment: @Blazemonger sometimes people use hyperbole. I think absolutely *everybody* understood his meaning.